# Regular Expression to Match a Single CSS Property

Tags: .net, css, regex

I currently have a large batch of HTML text and I have several CSS properties that resemble the following:

```
font:16px/normal Consolas;
font:16px/normal Arial;
font:12px/normal Courier;
```

which is also bundled with several other CSS properties and other associated HTML values and tags.

I've been trying to write a regular expression that will only grab these "font styles", so if I had the following two paragraphs:

```
<p style='font:16px/normal Arial; font-weight: x; color: y;'>Stack</p>
<span style='color: z; font:16px/normal Courier;'>Overflow</span>
<br />
<div style='font-family: Segoe UI; font-size: xx-large;'>Really large</div>
```

it would only match the properties beginning with `font:` and ending with a semicolon `;`.

I've played around using [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) and the closest I have gotten was:

```
\b(?:font[\s*\\]*:[\s*\\]*?(\b.*\b);)
```

which yielded the following results:

```
font:bold;                   //Match
font:12pt/normal Arial;      //Match
font:16px/normal Consolas;   //Match
font:12pt/normal Arial;      //Match
property: value;             //Not a Match
property: value value value; //Not a Match
```

but when I attempted to drop in a large block of HTML, things seemed to get muddled and large blocks were selected rather than within the bounds previously specified.

I'll be glad to provide any additional info and test data that I can.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the delimiters for get the exact match? Something like ^(\b(?:font[\s*\\]*:[\s*\\]*?(\b.*\b);))$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've left the `.*` greedy, which means it will eat and eat and only stop at the last semicolon available.  Add a question mark, i.e. `.*?` to make it non-greedy.

**Updated:**

```
    \b(?:font\s*?:\s*([^;>]*?)(?=[;">}]))
```

I've tested *every example on this page* at http://rubular.com/r/yRcED2n6wu.

Comment: Thanks acheong87. I never can seem to learn enough about regular expressions.

Comment: Note that `font: sans-serif 80%;` will never match.

Comment: Even after the update, I still see two ways this could fail, though such cases should be quite rare. First, obviously, comments ``/* ... */`` within the CSS; and second, one of the ``[;">}]`` characters appearing _within_ the font style's value, which I'm not positive is possible, except for the double-quotes, but only if the attribute uses single-quotes...

Answer (score 5):

**Try this**

```
\b((?:font:[^;]*?)(?:;|'))
```

**Explanation**

```
\b             # Assert position at a word boundary
(              # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   (?:            # Match the regular expression below
      font:          # Match the characters “font:” literally
      [^;]           # Match any character that is NOT a “;”
         *?             # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
   )
   (?:            # Match the regular expression below
                     # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         ;              # Match the character “;” literally
      |              # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
         &apos;              # Match the character “&apos;” literally
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Cylian - this works as well, and the explanation is quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this RegEx:

```
(?:font:[^;]*);
```

It matches `font:16px/normal Arial;` and `font:16px/normal Courier;` from your snippet above.

Comment: Thanks Barry - this seems to work so far. (And as usually I always feel like I over complicate Regular Expressions)

Comment: This will fail if the font style is last in its group and not closed by a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
\bfont\s*:\s*([^;}"'<>]+)(?<=\S)
```

Which will also work for cases where other answers fail. For example:

```
.foo { font: sans-serif 80% }
... style="font: sans-serif 80%" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking, but I think this problem can be solved by replacing your style tags with CSS.  The problem could be solved by placing the following in the Head tag of your HTML.

```
<style type="text/css">

h1 {

    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15;
    font-style:oblique;

}

h2 {
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 16;
    font-style:oblique;
 }
 h3 {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-style:oblique;
 }


</style>
```

Now, all you have to do to make an expression (or yourself) set one of these font styles is to surround it with a tag like so:

```
<h1> Cool Text!  </h1>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Sadly - in this case I don't have control over the input.

Comment: You could "take control" of the input by writing a PHP or Javascript code that just adds these on the front.  It would be fairly simple.